# Deployment error with Laravel App on Heroku

Tags: php, laravel, heroku

I am getting the below error when trying to deploy my Laravel app to heroku. Has anyone experienced this error before?

```
Running 'composer compile'...
remote:        > @php -dphar.readonly=0 bin/compile
remote:        Could not open input file: bin/compile
remote:        Script @php -dphar.readonly=0 bin/compile handling the compile event returned with error code 1
remote:
remote:  !     ERROR: Compile step failed!
remote:  !
remote:  !     Installation of dependencies was successful, but the custom
remote:  !     script you're using to perform actions after 'composer install'
remote:  !     failed with the error above.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Check that the 'compile' command(s) in the 'scripts' section of
remote:  !     your 'composer.json' are working properly and not running into
remote:  !     timeouts or memory limits.
remote:  !
remote:  !     For more information on the 'composer compile' step, refer to
remote:  !     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/php-support
remote:  !
remote:  !     REMINDER: the following warnings were emitted during the build;
remote:  !     check the details above, as they may be related to this error:
remote:  !     - Your 'composer.lock' is out of date!
remote:
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile PHP app.
```

Compile Script:

```
"scripts": {
        "compile": "@php -dphar.readonly=0 bin/compile"
    }
```

Comment: please post the deployment script, what is `bin/compile`?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to include that. I updated the post to include the script. I am not entirely sure what bin/compile is. I inherited this project from someone who doesn't like documentation.

Comment: What exactly is supposed be where bin/compile is? Is it the binary used for compilation?